# My website logo/image bumps down my hyperlinked text

Tags: html, css, notepad++

I am creating a draft website on notepad++ and I am wanting to have an image as my logo at the top left (not all the way left) next to my page links. However when I insert the image via html it moves the text links that were originally at the top downwards. How can I fix it so the links stay at the top next to the logo? (still centered)
[Green lines indicate the space it is creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68lfw.png)

HTML of logo

```
<img src="Images/website logo draft.png" height="100" width="200"/>
```

HTML hyperlinks

```
<div class="linkstyle">
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com"> Home</a>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Page 2</a>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Page 3</a>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Page 4</a>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Page5</a>
</div>
```

CSS link styling

```
.linkstyle{
  text-align: center;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size: 30px;
 }
```

more link styling

```
a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I have my img margin set to 50px which creates space between my three bottom images.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m11xrjz4/ All my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give `display: flex;` to parent and `margin: 0 auto;` to `.linkstyle`

```
body {
    display: flex;
}
```

Here body is the parent so, i have given to body.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6gx3q3cj/)**

Comment: @Droid2  it is because all other part also inside parent div. Just put only image and link in single div and give display flex to parent div like:  https://jsfiddle.net/6gx3q3cj/1/

Comment: Hello, Copied the code and this is result. https://imgur.com/ptRsetb text off center

Comment: @Droid2 if you don't want  center then remove. `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this css for img

```
img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Try below css for the div

```
.linkstyle {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: There are some typos, remove those `'` single quotes

Comment: Try for .linkstyle css     vertical-align:center
or If does not work then give padding top to this